# DocumentDb DateTime deserialization error

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

First of all, this is not about indexing or querying on DateTime values, like this [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/) covers.

It's about getting an error from the .NET SDK when deserializing a document with nested complex objects, where one of them has a DateTime property.

The structure of the document is like this:

```
class AccountBase : Document
{
    ... // omitted for brevity
}

class Account : AccountBase
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "calendar")]
    public Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
}

class Calendar
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entries")]
   public List<Entry> Entries{ get; set; }
}

class Entry
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entryDate")]
    public DateEpoch EntryDate { get; set; }
}

class DateEpoch
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "epoch")]
    public int Epoch
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.Date.Equals(null) || this.Date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                    ? int.MinValue
                    : this.Date.ToEpoch();
        }
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
public static int ToEpoch(this DateTime date)
{
    if (date == null) return int.MinValue;
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    TimeSpan epochTimeSpan = date - epoch;
    return (int)epochTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
}
```

And when trying to get this doc from azure a JsonReaderException is thrown:

*Error reading date. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'calendar.entries[0].entryDate', line 1, position 868.*

I have been using this DateEpoch object in *multiple* places before with no problem what so ever.
I was first thinking that [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/625) might have been related, but now I don't really have a clue.

Does any one recognize this problem?

**Edit:**

The data was requested, and it looks like this when browsed in Azure:

```
"calendar": {
 ... // omitted for brevity
    "entries": [
      {
        ... // omitted for brevity

        "entryDate": {
          "date": "2015-11-03T01:32:30.0600636Z",
          "epoch": 1446514350
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

**Nov 25 EDIT:**
Okay, this is still bothering me.

I tried doing it like Ryan CrawCour's example, but since it's a managed hash partitioned db, I cannot do it like that. The db is initialized according to the document db tutorials on managed hash partitioned dbs.

So, the following type of request can be done:

```
        public void DeserializeAccount()
        {
            using (_client)
            {
                var state = new AccountState(Guid.NewGuid());
                var account = new Account(state)
                {
                    Calendar = new Calendar
                    {
                        Entries = new List<Entry> 
                        { 
                            new Entry(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.UtcNow)
                        }
                    }
                };

                var doc = _client.CreateDocumentAsync(_database.SelfLink, account).Result;

                foreach (Account acc in _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Account>(_database.SelfLink)
                                    .Where(d => d.Id == doc.Resource.Id)
                                    .AsEnumerable())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(acc.ToString());
                };
            }
        }
```

Still getting the same error message:

> Error reading date. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path
>   'calendar.entries[0].entryDate', line 1, position 541.

Comment: Post the *data* that causes the issue. Most likely the data doesn't have the same shape as your objects and `epoch` has nothing to do with it (`Unexpected token: StartObject`)

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  It would appear the JSON does not match your data model and looks something like `{ "date": { ... }}`.

Comment: I updated with the JSON. Although, it was entered with the same model just seconds before trying to retreive it, so nothing has changed in my code that would impede the serialization.

Comment: Panagiotis, I guess you're saying that the issue is in the beginning of the json? I know it's not about the epoch, just wanted to show what I was doing there. I've always thought it's about the datetime object somehow.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are making the call to retrieve the document from the db.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. (see "answer" below). Have you overridden the version of JSON.NET that ships with the DocumentDB SDK?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, couldn't reproduce it myself, so I have no idea what happened. Using JSON.NET 7.0.0.0.

Comment: Edit: I _can_ reproduce it. See original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this.

I copied your objects, as they were here. And then using the following code was able to save a document and then retrieve it, and have it desearialized back in to the Account type.

```
        using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey))
        {
            var collLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            var account = new Account { Calendar = new Calendar{ Entries = new List<Entry> { new Entry { EntryDate = new DateEpoch { Date = DateTime.UtcNow } } }} };

            var doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync(collLink, account).Result;

            foreach (Account acc in client.CreateDocumentQuery<Account>(collLink)
                                .Where(d => d.Id == doc.Resource.Id)
                                .AsEnumerable())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(acc.ToString());
            };
        }
```

As per this screengrab.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I couldn't reproduce it myself, so I actually have no idea what happened here.

Comment: Okay, so there's a bit more to it than that. First of all, I'm using a Managed Hash Partitioned Db. So I cannot do the above operation. Look at the original post for more details.